# Access element tagnames from child in parent

Tags: angular

I have two components, ParentComponent and ChildComponent:

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-selector #parent></child-selector>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('parent', { read: ElementRef }) parent: ElementRef<any>;


doThis(event) {
    this.parent.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(e => {
        if (e.tagName === 'GRIDSTER-ITEM') {
          console.log("do stuff here");
        }
      });
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<gridster>
    <grister-item></gridster-item>
<gridster>
```

**child.component.ts**

The code would work if it would be the same component, the child html would be directly in the parent and `#parent` would be on element `<gridster>`.

What should I use instead of ElementRef?
Or maybe another solution?

Comment: You should use `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside your parent template and `@ContentChildren` decorator to reference components inside

Answer (score 1):

You could make the gridster-item elements available to the child component.

child.component.ts

```
@ViewChildren(GridsterItemComponent) gridsterItems;
```

parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent;

doSomething() {
  this.childComponent.gridsterItems.callSomeMethod();
}
```